# Man-in-the-middle attack on text-book RSA PKE

Tags: encryption, rsa, public-key, man-in-the-middle

I am attempting to solve the following problem:

I know the following:
3 messages are being sent between Alice and Bob, all messages are encrypted with the known public key $(d,N)$:

1. Alice sends Bob: $m_1=E(R_1);$ $R_1$ is a 28-bit number.
2. Bob sends Alice: $m_2=E(R_2,R_1);$ $R_2$ is a 28-bit number and $R_1$ follows (i.e, 
   $p_2 = (2^{28} * R_2 + R_1)$ if i am not mistaken)
3. Alice sends Bob: $m_3=E(R_2,R_1,R_3);$ $R_3$ is a 156-bit number known *in advance*.

The goal is to alter $R_3$'s value which is about to be sent to Bob to a new value (first 7 bits only).

The best I could come up with is to precompute all possible 28-bit number encryptions which will allow me to know $R_1$'s value when sent by Alice -> then easily figure out $R_2$'s value -> send my desired $R_3$ value to Bob.

Is there a neater (and more feasible) way to do so?

Comment: Hint: RSA is multiplicative, you can multiply and [divide](https://medium.com/asecuritysite-when-bob-met-alice/homomorphic-encryption-for-division-with-rsa-2f1e97058f91)

Comment: I forgot to state that i have been asked not to use the RSA's multiplicative nature

Answer (score 1):

I see four ways how to attack this scheme

**1) RSA malleability**
Suggested in comments

**2) If $e=3$ then**
Trivial attack exists. Hint: What is the minimal possible size of $N$?

**3) If the attack is active(MiTM)**
Cheaper attack exists. Hint: Treat the task as a set of Oracles:

- $Oracle0: n \mapsto E(n)$ - If you know $(e,N)$, you can encrypt any $n$.
- $Oracle1: \epsilon \mapsto E(R_1)$
- $Oracle2: E(n) \mapsto E(R_2*2^{28}+n)$
- $Oracle3: E(n) \mapsto E(n*2^{156}+R_3)$ - Are you sure?

**4) You treat it as a blackbox**
Your solution